# i am getting an error "TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment"

Tags: python, dictionary

I am a beginner in python. I am trying to pass a query file i.e file2 which contains the list of some protein accession numbers  to check the presence of those accessions in the parent tab-delimited dictionary file i.e Book2.txt, I am getting an error "TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment"

my code goes as follows:

```
for i in open ("Book2.txt"):
    split_i=i.split('\t')
    dict['Master Protein Accessions']=i.rstrip //TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment   
for j in open("file2.txt"):
    if j.rstrip in dict:
        print(dict(j.rstrip))
```

Comment: `dict` already exists and it means dictionary type, so you cannot do `dict['Master Protein Accessions']=`

Comment: thank you @h4z3 so can you help me out with the correct  code structure?

Comment: There's so much things wrong with your code that I'd suggest understanding your own code first. Right now almost every line has something wrong with it... (Only lines with `open` look fine...) You'd also need to understand how dictionaries work - right now 3rd line would overwrite your entry with last element, and 6th line 1) is not how you search info in dict. 2) The only key in your dict would be `'Master Protein Accessions'` anyway...

Answer (score 0):

first of all "dict" is a keyword you cant use as dictionary name and then you have to create an empty dictionary or default dictionary to assign some value.

so you can do:

```
d = {} or d = dict()
for i in open ("Book2.txt"):
    split_i=i.split('\t')
    d['Master Protein Accessions']=i.rstrip()    
for j in open("file2.txt"):
    if j.rstrip() in d:
        print(d[j.rstrip()])
```

Comment: This is still wrong. The OPs code has more problems than just this one thing...

Comment: you will need to put parenthesis after `rstrip`

Comment: i will give the situation can you pls frame the code for me :\

Answer (score 0):

```
dicts = {}
for i in open('Book2.txt'):
    split_i = i.split('\t')
    dicts[split_i[0]] = i.rstrip()

for j in open('file2.txt'):
    if j.rstrip() in dicts:
        print(dicts[j.rstrip()]
```